# Ubuntu - iptables stops redirecting port 80 to 8080 suddenly without any pattern

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, routing

I have a ubuntu VPS which I am using to host my java based application.  It has tomcat installed on port 8080.

I have used below iptable command to route traffic from port 80 to 8080. Honestly, I am not a expert on this. I just copied this command from some webpage and it is working fine

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Now problem is, I don't know why but this routing suddenly stops working. There is no pattern. This happens out of the blue. So, I have to SSH to machine and run this command again. So everything start working again

Can anybody help me on

1. Either to get this permanently fixed. so, that it never stops routing.
2. OR suggest me a way to automate this. i.e. always check if this routing is working, if not, run the command

Comment: Just some random thoughts: Could it be that your VPS reboots due to some error and loses its settings? Can you check uptime after problems? Also, could it be that some kind of external management agent is resetting this?

Comment: @JannePaalijarvi Its not the case. I just checked uptime and it is 74 days. So, OS is not rebooted. Thats sure.

Comment: Is there a way I can automate it, check if routing is configured correctly every 5 mins. If not, correct it?

Comment: Yeah, use a firewall daemon. They're a dime a dozen nowadays. Check out firewalld (comes default in RHEL-based systems) or ufw (comes default in Ubuntu-based systems).

Answer (score 0):

First a big fat disclaimer: THE FOLLOWING IS THE WRONG WAY TO DO WHAT YOU NEED. The following solution is fixing the symptoms and not figuring out the root cause. Anyways:

We need 2 things to automate this. A script that checks and fixes the redirection and a scheduler to run it.

First the script. Place following as script in `/usr/local/sbin/check_80_redirections.sh` and for simplicity make it executable and readable by everyone `chmod a+rx /usr/local/sbin/check_80_redirections.sh` . The actual script:

```
#!/bin/sh

REDIR_TAG="port_80_redir_on"

/sbin/iptables -t nat -n -L | grep "$REDIR_TAG" > /dev/null

if [ "$?" -ne 0 ];
then
    # 0 means match, so -ne 0 means no match => redo iptables
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080 -m comment --comment "$REDIR_TAG"
fi
```

Next the scheduler part. We can use the cron subsystem of your distribution. Edit `/etc/crontab` and place following as last line:

`*/5 *   * * *   root    /usr/local/sbin/check_80_redirections.sh`

I checked this on Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine. I added the script and crontab modifications. I can see the rule in effect. If I manually remove the rule, in a few minutes it comes back.

I'd still strongly advice you to figure out what is the root cause needing this workaround.

Comment: Thank You Janne. Thanks for pointing out disclaimer. As it is a prod server, I want to solve problem first. Then I can invest time during off business hours to find out solution. I created below script

Comment: #!/bin/sh

REDIR_TAG="8080"

/sbin/iptables -t nat -n -L | grep "$REDIR_TAG" > /dev/null

if [ "$?" -ne 0 ];
then
    # 0 means match, so -ne 0 means no match => redo iptables
    /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080 -m comment --comment "$REDIR_TAG"
fi

return 0

Comment: Want to check port 8080. But when I execute it getting error /usr/local/bin/check_80_redirections.sh: line 13: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script. Apologies for naive question. I am backend dev and not very familiar with managing servers

Comment: Heh, I'm actually embedded developer, so no worries :D You can take away the return, I edited it away also if it causes problems on some systems.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs and help Janne. However, that didn't solved the issue. I manually redirected port to 8079, then executed the script. However, port was not being redirected back to 8080. So, worked on an alternative and fortunately able to implement

Comment: What I think happened you added 8079-rule overtaking the 8080 script rule. The 8080 script rule was still there probably. My script detected that "hey, the 8080 rule exists, we don't need to do anything". I don't think you should add new rules "on top" of old ones for this problem. But if what you created works now for something feasible to you, good.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding below script to /opt/shellscripts/curl.sh. This script hits my application URL and checks if 200 response is received.

```
status=$(curl -Is http://www.***.in/customer | head -n 1)
echo $status
if [[ ${status} != "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ]]
then
        echo "executing command"
        eval $(sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080)
fi
```

Then added below entry to crontab

```
* * * * * /opt/shellscripts/curl.sh
```